# Change Property of db.Model to custom Type

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm trying to change the Property several Fields on my GAE AppEngine to a custom Type (Encrypted Content).

Most of them are currently String or Text Properties. Since we have multiple millions of Entries in our DB, migration is not an easy task. I'm looking for a best practise, here is what I think will work best but this might be very challenging to execution time limits plus I'm a little bit frightened about the costs for this task.

1. clone table to tmp_table
2. delete table
3. create table with new attributes
4. insert values from tmp_table into table

What sounds like a short hiking trip on most environments feels a little bit more complex on GAE ;)

My Questions to you:
- Are there any know best practises you are aware of / did you already achieve this challenge & how?
- Any Idea how to trigger the process (I would estimate it takes several minutes so the 60 second limit

Comment: Are you using the datastore or Cloud SQL? Edit: I assume that since you refer to String and Text Properties, it is the datastore

Comment: There are no tables.  You need to stop thinking in those terms.

Comment: You haven't said if you can perform a migration of content over time or it all has to happen during a fixed period where you suspend all updates.  This requirement will heavily affect what approach you take.

Comment: Have you read Updating Your Model's Schema - https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema  it describes an approach and some things you should consider like having entities with different sets of properties over time.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using Datastore and I've read the guide you posted. I'm going to update this in a while how my solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

Its not sql. You dont clone or delete 'tables', no such thing in the datastore.
To do the migration you would use task queues to run through a query. You probably need to stop your frontend while doing so. Task queues have a longer limit than the 60sec you mention and each taskqueue will  create another one until you finish pro essing all items in your query.
Yiu also complain that its harder than other enviroments but it isnt so. The problem maybe is that you chose to use the datastore instead of cloud sql which you could also have used. Each has its pros and cons.